# R move whole folder to another directory

Tags: r, directory, move

I would like to move the whole folder from one directory to another, this is my code,

```
folder_old_path = "C:/Users/abc/Downloads/managerA"
path_new = "C:/User/abc/Desktop/managerA"
current_files = list.files(folder_old_path, full.names = TRUE)
file.copy(from = current_files, to = path_new, 
          overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE, copy.mode = TRUE)
```

However, I am getting this error msg

> Error in file.copy(from = current_files, to = path_new, overwrite = recursive,  : 
>     more 'from' files than 'to' files

any idea how to fix this? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that for the new path you mean "User," not "Users" as above?

Comment: Does `path_new` exist already? The copy won't create the new folder.

Comment: finally figure out, need to create the new path folder first. thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 5):

```
library(ff)
from <- "~/Path1/"            #Current path of your folder
to   <- "~/Path2/"            #Path you want to move it.
path1 <- paste0(from,"NameOfMyFolder")
path2 <- paste0(to,"NameOfMyFolder")
file.move(path1,path2)
```

Try using this little code.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest:

`file.rename(folder_old_path, path_new)`

If you want to check if `path_new` already exists you can expand the above to:

```
if (dir.exists(path_new) {
  print(paste("already exists so recurively deleting path_new", path_new))
  unlink(path_new, recursive = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the `current_files = list.files(folder_old_path, full.names = TRUE)` step is unnecessary. If my understanding of the [R file documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/files) is correct, then you should be able to just use the following:

```
folder_old_path = "C:/Users/abc/Downloads/managerA"
path_new = "C:/User/abc/Desktop/managerA"
file.copy(from = folder_old_path, to = path_new, 
          overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE, copy.mode = TRUE)
```

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to create a new list of files (iterate over the `current_files` and replace `folder_old_path` with `folder_new_path` for each item in the list) and call `file.copy` on those:

```
folder_old_path = "C:/Users/abc/Downloads/managerA"
path_new = "C:/User/abc/Desktop/managerA"
current_files = list.files(folder_old_path, full.names = TRUE)
new_files = # replace folder_old_path with path_new for every file in current_files
file.copy(from = current_files, to = new_files, 
          overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE, copy.mode = TRUE)
```

... this all assumes (of course) that both `folder_old_path` and `path_new` exist and you have the correct permissions on them.

The linked page does contain a caveat/note about windows paths:

> There is no guarantee that these functions will handle Windows
>   relative paths of the form `d:path`: try `d:./path` instead. In
>   particular, `d:` is not recognized as a directory. Nor are `\\?\` prefixes
>   (and similar) supported.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you should be able to simply:

1) make the OTHER_DIR if needed. If it is a subdirectory to OUTPUT_DIR then:
`dir.create(file.path(OUTPUT_DIR, OTHER_DIR), showWarnings = FALSE)
setwd(file.path(OUTPUT_DIR, OTHER_DIR))`

`dir.create()` will just print a warning if the directory exists. If you want to see the warning, just remove the `showWarnings = FALSE`.

If it is just another directory at the same level as OUTPUT_DIR then:

`dir.create(OTHER_DIR)`

2) Then move the file (e.g. if OTHER_DIR is at the same level as OUTPUT_DIR):

`file.rename("C:/OUTPUT_DIR/file.csv", "C:/OTHER_DIR/file.csv")`